# Dynamic Arrays in Java - What are my options?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, arraylist

Now, before you start clicking the down arrow on this question, hear me out.

I am doing a paper on Dynamic Arrays in my Java class. I already know the normal Arrays (1D and 2D) and the ArrayList. Now, My teacher claims there are more kinds of dynamic arrays, but she refuses to tell me anything since I'm the one that is suppose to do the work.

I have searched around, and the only thing I found was Linked List, and it doesn't even work with arrays. I simply can't find anything anywhere of other Dynamic Arrays. Could someone explain to me what are the types of dynamic arrays (if there are more then ArrayList) and maybe give me some insight about it? If not, just the types would be good. Really struggling here...

Thanks.

EDIT: Turns out she wants Dynamic data structures, not arrays. so imagine everytime you read arrays up there it was written "data structures". sorry

EDIT: So let me see if I got it all: I need to talk about java collections, java vectors, and Lists (talking a litle bit of all the List types). Anything missing?

Comment: Vector (which BTW is obsolete)? CopyOnWriteArrayList? There are a few other classes which are backed by an array - most of them implement the List interface so a good starting point would be the [List javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (section: *All Known Implementing Classes*)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html

Comment: @assylias thanks, thats really usefull for the work, even if not usefull in programming xD

Comment: Do you have a definition for "Dynamic Array"?

Comment: Have a look at the JCF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) for some more information on the different collections in java.

Comment: @Thilo well... an array with the possibility of changing its size?

Comment: Java Fast List? http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastList.html

Comment: Is there any reasonable chance that your teacher's Java expertise is somewhat more limited than is implied here? Seeing your edit, I'd safely assume that a summary of the Collection interface type hierarchy + its implementations is what she has in mind.

Comment: OK so I have collections, vectors, fastlists, and linkedlists. Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: @user3357221: make sure that you differentiate strictly between interfaces and implementations!

Comment: @okiharaherbst She is a bad teacher, since she doesn't know how to teach, she just makes us do works and exercises without actually explaining and then throws new stuff into the tests. having that aside, by my understanding, she wants me to say what are the existing dynamic data structures in java (all types) and examples on how to use them.

Comment: She seems to be talking about 'mutable' data structures (as opposed to immutable ones).  Or possibly resizable structures (arrays are not resizable but are always mutable - unless 0-length; `List` is resizeable, and may or may not be mutable, depending on the implementation - have a look at `Collections.unmodifiableList()` for example).  'Mutable' means most data structures in Java, since Java (historically) favours mutability (unlike, say, Clojure).  Try reading up on `Set` and `Map` and some of their implementations (e.g. `TreeSet`, `HashMap`).

Comment: @Paul dynamic = resizable

Comment: @user3357221: So read up on collections (that's the API side) and the differences of their implementations (eg. ArrayList vs LinkedList) and summarize all this with potential use cases and advantages/drawbacks. If you want to sound cool, you can even say a few things about the newly introduced streams (Java 8).

Comment: You might want to consider the different *aspects* of these collections: their type (e.g. `List`, `Set`, `Map`); their mutability; their 'dynamism' (resizable?); their efficiency (in time and space - for various operations); how they manage their underlying structure (for example, `ArrayList` doesn't resize the underlying array for every element added); their synchronization (thread safety).  Even though you probably don't need to include all these (given what you were asked for) knowing about them would probably help decide what to include.  You'd then know more than your teacher too. :-)

Comment: What about arrays with different dimensions? `int[][] array = new int[2][]; array[0] = new int[23]; array[1] = new int[47];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CopyOnArrayList`same as `ArrayList` but allows concurrent modifications.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList and LinkedList based on the dynamic array concepts
for more information about list
please check [here](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~bobw/CS210/Lecture16.pdf)